# Resize iOS App Preview for all devices

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios-simulator

I am soooo close to submitting my app to the app store, but we have one problem. App Previews. You need 1 preview for EVERY device, and I'm sorry I don't have all your devices apple :( . Is there anyway to automatically resize my one app preview I have already without losing MAJOR quality?

Comment: "You need 1 preview for EVERY device" Actually that's no longer true. You submit a preview for _one_ device size and it will be resized for you automatically at iTunes Connect. See WWDC 2016 video 305.

Comment: I would check out [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane). it might take a bit to set up but it's designed for making your app submission process as simple as possible. It will automatically generate all the screenshots you need.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it, is to record an App Preview for the biggest screen size and then scale it down with tools like After Effects or Final Cut Pro. I'm not 100% sure, if you can also do it with iMovie. If you're supporting iPad, you need to create another version for iPads.

Here are the [official sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW34) (Landscape only for simplification):

> 5 Series: 1920 x 1080 (< Standard 1080p 16:9 aspect ratio) or 1136 x
> 640
>
> iPhone 6: 1334 x 750 (~ 70% of 1080p)
>
> iPhone 6 Plus: 1920 x 1080
>
> AppleTV: 1920 x 1080
>
> iPad: 1200 x 900 or 1600 x 1200 (4:3 aspect ratio)

I suggest you capture the material for the App Previews with an iPhone 6 Plus (real device or simulator if that works for you) and then scale it down for the best quality. If you don't have an iPhone 6 Plus, you can use an iPhone 6, but you will lose quality.

**Summary:** You only need 2 different App Previews - with regards to resolutions - if you are only supporting iPhones. (3 if you are supporting iPads.)